# How to operate jQuery object correctly?

Tags: jquery

```
$('table.diyform').children('tbody').children('tr').each(function() {
    var $tds = $(this).children('td');
    var label = $tds[0].find('a').html();
    var required = $tds[0].find('input').html();
});
```

The problem lies in `$tds[0]` but I don't know the correct way to do it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use [eq](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index).

```
$('table.diyform').children('tbody').children('tr').each(function() {
        var $tds = $(this).children('td');
        var label = $tds.eq(0).find('a').html();
        var required = $tds.eq(0).find('input').html();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
var tds = $(this).children('td');
var label = $(tds).find('a').html();
```